# Notepad++ Replace text that ends with number

Tags: notepad++

In a txt file , I want to replace string between "live/" and "/number"

```
just a random text/live/y8mJepPsAk/UgZtTKd6A8/79953
just a random text/live/SvSvuq6JV5/eE3dg0bAMr/79954
just a random text/live/eME6hoeNV9/PJa5HwhUnF/88974
just a random text/live/bUue7Vprac/sue0ZmGzwy/78385
just a random text/live/UznB0niAEp/MgspVk69tX/93994
```

I tried this code :

```
Replace : live/.*?/[0-9]
Replace with : live/my-new-text/
```

But the problem is that the first number after "/" is deleted.

Comment: Try `(/live/).*(/\d+)$` and replace with `\1my-new-text\2` (do not forget to enable Regular Expression mode).

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=live/).+?(?=/\d+$)`
- Replace with: `my-new-text`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

---

Depending on Npp version you can use instead:

- Find what: `live/\K.+?(?=/\d+$)`

---

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=live/)  : positive lookbehind, make sure we have "live/" before
.+?         : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
(?=/\d+$)   : positive lookahead, make sure we have slash and 1 or more digits
```

**Result for given example:**

```
just a random text/live/my-new-text/79953
just a random text/live/my-new-text/79954
just a random text/live/my-new-text/88974
just a random text/live/my-new-text/78385
just a random text/live/my-new-text/93994
```

Comment: Thank you Toto but its not working : 

(?<=live/).+?(?=/\d+$) doesn't change anything

Comment: @ChaoukiAnass:Which version are you using? See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor fix to your original regexp:

`live/.*?/(?=[0-9])`

Use a positive lookahead instead of a number. That way It won't be replaced.

Another alternative is matching the number and later restore it with \1:

```
Replace : live/.*?/([0-9])
Replace with : live/my-new-text/\1
```